# How do I take an array of strings and separate them further into objects?

Tags: java, arrays, string, object, arraylist

I have an array of strings identifying a pet name, type of animal, age and their owner's name (each attribute is separated by a comma):

```
String[] petInfo = ["Spot, dog, 2, Joey", "Kip, dog, 3, Jack", "Snuffles, cat, 1, Jane" , "Franklin, turtle, 4, Arthur",...]
```

I created a pet class with members string petName, string type, int age and string ownerName.

```
public class Pet
{
string petName; 
string type;
int age;
string ownerName;

//getters
}
```

In my main I declared

```
List<Pet> pets = new ArrayList<Pet>();
```

I want to create an array of pet objects using an arraylist. I know I have to use split to get through the original array but that leaves me with another array of comma separated values for one pet. How do I write a loop that can go through the petInfo array and add those values to each pet object in my list?

Comment: `new Pet(arr[0], arr[1], arr[2], arr[3])` (`arr` is the split array and assuming you have a constructor taking the four arguments)

Comment: @user7 You mean `new Pet(arr[0], arr[1], Integer.parseInt(arr[2]), arr[3])`

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Ya. good catch

Comment: Sorry i'm not following @user7. Are you referring to the arraylist declaration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Here is all you need:**

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

    public class Main {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            String[] petInfo = {"Spot, dog, 2, Joey", "Kip, dog, 3, Jack", "Snuffles, cat, 1, Jane" , "Franklin, turtle, 4, Arthur"};
            List<Pet> pets = new ArrayList<Pet>();
            for (String singlePetInfo : petInfo) {
                pets.add(getPetFromString(singlePetInfo));
            }

            pets.forEach(System.out::println);
        }

        private static Pet getPetFromString(String petDescription){
            String[] split = petDescription.split(", ");
            return new Pet(split[0], split[1], Integer.parseInt(split[2]), split[3]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where does the '.add' method and .forEach come from? edit: missed the s, refers to the list

Comment: .add() method adds your Pet object to list.


.forEach is kinda nicer way in Java 8 to iterate over list which takes Consumer as an argument, but you can still use traditional for loop to iterate over list and print every pet

Comment: weird in the getPetFromString method i'm getting java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. going through my array, it has a thousand different pets, could a messed up string cause that? for example, no pet age etc?

Comment: Yes, it can be the reason.

Comment: Ah, it was the space after the comma for some reason

Answer (score 1):

A very verbose example: This method takes the array and converts the pet parts to a pet. Returning the list of pets at the end.

```
public List<Pet> toPets(String[] petArray) {
  List<Pet> pets = new ArrayList();
  for (String petAsString: petArray) {
     String[] petParts = petAsString.split(",");
     String petName = petParts[0].trim();
     String type = petParts[1].trim();
     int age = Integer.parseInt(petParts[2].trim());
     String ownerName = petParts[3].trim();
     Pet pet = new Pet(petName, type, age, ownerName);
     pets.add(pet);
  }
  return pets;
}
```

Comment: Splitting via ", " rather than "," avoids .trim() usage

Comment: true, if you assume the spaces are always well formatted like that

Comment: Splitting via ", " is worst usage. You are assuming there will be only one space char. But it can have many different combinations. Best solution is using it with true regex. "\\s*,\\s*" is better solution. You can handle all possible spacing with this regex.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a solution. There are two key points. Splitting string can cause faulty solutions. That's why, I added a proper regex. Also you need to take care of integer conversion. Using integer class makes it easy for you.

```
    String[] petInfo = {"Spot, dog, 2, Joey", "Kip, dog, 3, Jack", "Snuffles, cat, 1, Jane" , "Franklin, turtle, 4, Arthur"};
    List<Pet> pets = new ArrayList<Pet>();

    for (int i = 0; i < petInfo.length; i++) {
        String[] pet = petInfo[i].split("\\s*,\\s*");
        pets.add(new Pet(pet[0], pet[1], Integer.parseInt(pet[2]), pet[3]));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Constructor or helper method to create `Pet` object from given string.

Following is code snippet for constructor. See [here the complete working code](https://ideone.com/fJfEri):

```
Pet(String val)
{
    String[] vals = val.trim().split(",");
    petName = vals[0].trim();
    type = vals[1].trim();
    age = Integer.valueOf(vals[2].trim());
    ownerName = vals[3].trim();
}
```

To use it, you can do something like following:

```
    String[] petInfo = new String[]{"Spot, dog, 2, Joey", 
        "Kip, dog, 3, Jack", "Snuffles, cat, 1, Jane" , "Franklin, turtle, 4, Arthur"};
    ArrayList<Pet> list = new ArrayList();
    for(String p:petInfo)
    {
        list.add(new Pet(p));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Take your `petInfo` array and go through it with a `for` loop. Then you split your string and create a new `Pet` object, then you can just add it to your `List<Pet>` called `pets`

```
List<Pet> pets = new ArrayList<Pet>();

//Renamed it to petInfos, for better usage in the for loop
String[] petInfos = ["Spot, dog, 2, Joey", "Kip, dog, 3, Jack", "Snuffles, cat, 1, Jane" ,
    "Franklin, turtle, 4, Arthur",...]

for(String petInfo : petInfos){
   String[] petInfoSplitted = petInfo.split(", ");

   pets.add(new Pet(petInfoSplitted[0], petInfoSplitted[1],
       Integer.parseInt(petInfoSplitted[2]), petInfoSplitted[3]);
}
```

I hope my awnser was helpfull.